# Groovy MarkupBuilder name conflict

Tags: groovy, markupbuilder

I have this code:

```
String buildCatalog(Catalog catalog) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    xml.catalog(xmlns:'http://www.sybrium.com/XMLSchema/NodeCatalog') {
        'identity'() {
            groupId(catalog.groupId)
            artifactId(catalog.artifactId)
            version(catalog.version)
        }
    }

    return writer.toString();
}
```

It produces this xml:

```
<catalog xmlns='http://www.sybrium.com/XMLSchema/NodeCatalog'>
  <groupId>sample.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</catalog>
```

Notice that the "identity" tag is missing... I've tried everything in the world to get that node to appear. I'm ripping my hair out!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There might be a better way, but one trick is to call `invokeMethod` directly:

```
String buildCatalog(Catalog catalog) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    xml.catalog(xmlns:'http://www.sybrium.com/XMLSchema/NodeCatalog') {
        delegate.invokeMethod('identity', [{
            groupId(catalog.groupId)
            artifactId(catalog.artifactId)
            version(catalog.version)
        }])
    }

    return writer.toString();
}
```

This is effectively what Groovy is doing behind the scenes.  I couldn't get `delegate.identity` or `owner.identity` to work, which are the usual tricks.

---

**Edit**: I figured out what's going on.

Groovy [adds a method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#identity%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) with a signature of `identity(Closure c)` to every object.

This means that when you tried to dynamically invoke the `identity` element on the XML builder, while passing in a single closure argument, it was calling the `identity()` method, which is like calling `delegate({...})` on the outer closure.

Using the `invokeMethod` trick forces Groovy to bypass the Meta Object Protocol and treat the method as a dynamic method, even though the `identity` method already exists on the MetaObject.

Knowing this, we can put together a better, more legible solution.  All we have to do is change the signature of the method, like so:

```
String buildCatalog(Catalog catalog) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    xml.catalog(xmlns:'http://www.sybrium.com/XMLSchema/NodeCatalog') {
        // NOTE: LEAVE the empty map here to prevent calling the identity method!
        identity([:]) {
            groupId(catalog.groupId)
            artifactId(catalog.artifactId)
            version(catalog.version)
        }
    }

    return writer.toString();
}
```

This is much more readable, it's clearer the intent, and the comment should (hopefully) prevent anyone from removing the "unnecessary" empty map.

Comment: That worked, but can you explain this? What is delegate and why is delegate.identity different from delegate.invokeMethod('identity')?

Comment: FYI: I tracked this down by using the GroovyConsole to inspect the XML object.  This let me know that the `identity` method already existed with a single `Closure` as its argument.

Comment: I got the same issue when used 'version' and 'description' fields, thankfully after searching on Github I found reference this answer!