# Force Boolean Type with jOOQ throws NPE

Tags: java, oracle, jooq

I'm trying to use "forced types" for BOOLEANs when generating classes for our Oracle database with jOOQ 3.7.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE outable_name
(
  id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  -- ...
  some_boolean_field INTEGER DEFAULT 0  NOT NULL
);
```

To generate the Java classes `Gradle`is used. The relevant part looks like this:

```
database() {
  name('org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase')
  inputSchema(properties.getProperty('db.user'))
  includes('.*')   
  forcedTypes() {
    forcedType() {
      name('BOOLEAN')
      expression('some_boolean_field')
      types('.*')
    }
  }
}
```

When running the gradle-task with info-output the following error is thrown:

```
Error while generating table record ***.*** (obfuscated)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Matcher.java:1283)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Matcher.java:309)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Matcher.java:229)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Pattern.java:1093)
        at org.jooq.util.AbstractTypedElementDefinition.mapDefinedType(AbstractTypedElementDefinition.java:174)
        at org.jooq.util.AbstractTypedElementDefinition.getType(AbstractTypedElementDefinition.java:114)
        at org.jooq.util.DefaultColumnDefinition.getType(DefaultColumnDefinition.java:51)
        at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.refRowType(JavaGenerator.java:1241)
        at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateRecord(JavaGenerator.java:838)
        at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateRecord(JavaGenerator.java:797)
        at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateRecord(JavaGenerator.java:785)
        at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generateRecords(JavaGenerator.java:772)
        at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:327)
        at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:267)
        at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:434)
        at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:180)
        at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool$generate.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at ...
```

Comment: I think you might be running into [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11388838/521799), but I'm not sure which one of the expressions (perhaps `expression` ?) is the conflicting one...

Answer (score 1):

Call "name" directly with `invokeMethod`:

```
database() {
  name('org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase')
  inputSchema(properties.getProperty('db.user'))
  includes('.*')   
  forcedTypes() {
    forcedType() {
      delegate.invokeMethod('name', [
                                      'BOOLEAN'
                                    ]
      )
     expression('.*\\.is_.*|.*\\.has_.*')
     types('CHAR\\(1\\)')
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation in [Groovy MarkupBuilder name conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11388838/521799)