# jOOQ code generation error : The <generator/> tag is mandatory

Tags: jooq

Here is my configuration file :

```
<configuration>
  <jdbc>
    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db</url>
    <user>myuser</user>
    <password>mypwd</password>
  </jdbc>
  <generator>
    <database>
      <name>org.jooq.util.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
    </database>
    <generate>
      <pojos>true</pojos>
      <daos>true</daos>
    </generate>
    <target>
      <packageName>com.myproject.gen</packageName>
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    </target>
  </generator>
</configuration>
```

It used to work but now I have the following error :

> `The <generator/> tag is mandatory`

I use jOOQ 3.8.2

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your XML code. Do you perhaps have any weird whitespace characters in your XML file?

Comment: I'm using Groovy Xml Markup Builder and what you see above is the generated result. Unfortunately, as it is generated, I don't think there is any weird white space characters and any problem with the markup.. Is there any doc to create the configuration object programmatically ?

Comment: Yes, this is how to do it programmatically: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic. Do note, there are some caveats when using the Xml Markup Builder. They're documented here: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle (look for "caveat") and here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389034/521799

Comment: ok perfect, thank you. As I don't see any advantages generating dynamic xml, doing it programmatically is the correct solution for my problem. Could you create an answer so I can give you the points you deserve for your help.

Comment: Well, I didn't answer your question :) Perhaps someone else will find the real answer in the future. I have enough "karma", don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Found that in JOOQ > 3.8 the encoding in target tag is mandatory.
Try to add the `<encoding>` in the `<target>` tag, i.ex. `<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>`

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this in my code. Make sure the code gen library matches the xsd version. See my [example](https://github.com/cjemison/jooq_example/blob/master/build.gradle)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry. I am new to this.  I didn't understand the rules.

Comment: Yes this place can be a bit overwhelming at first.  Suggest you read and re-read as much of the help section as you can manage. Good luck.