# "Ambiguous type name" error while generating code with jOOQ and Gradle

Tags: gradle, code-generation, jooq

When I try to generate code with jOOQ I get a lot of errors like:

```
     Ambiguous type name      :
The object pg_catalog.unnest generates a type org.jooq.example.gradle.db.pg_catalog.tables.Unnest
    which conflicts with the existing type
    org.jooq.example.gradle.db.pg_catalog.tables.Unnest on some operating systems.
    Use a custom generator strategy to disambiguate the types.
```

Not sure what an operating system should have to do with it. Never used jOOQ before. As I understand it should connect to a Postgres db and generate some java code that can be used later to run queries against the db.

I have the following configuration in `build.gradle` (taken from https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-gradle/)

```
// Use your favourite XML builder to construct the code generation configuration file
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
        .configuration('xmlns': 'http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.13.0.xsd') {
            jdbc() {
                driver('org.postgresql.Driver')
                url('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/metrics')
                user('postgres')
                password('pwd')
            }
            generator() {
                database() {
                }

                // Watch out for this caveat when using MarkupBuilder with "reserved names"
                // - https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4797
                // - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389034/521799
                // - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/wi4S9rRxk4A
                generate() {
                }
                target() {
                    packageName('org.jooq.example.gradle.db')
                    directory('src/main/java')
                }
            }
        }

// Run the code generator
// ----------------------
org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(writer.toString())
```

As a beginner I'm overwhelmed with this error...

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the schema

```
database() {
inputSchema('public')
}
```

This solved the problem