# Cannot resolve class TableOptions generated by jOOQ

Tags: gradle, code-generation, jooq

I'm using jOOQ 3.13.0 with Gradle.

Here are some related excerpts from the `build.gradle`

```
...

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.13.3'
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    compile 'org.jooq:jooq:3.13.3'
}

...

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(writer)
        .configuration('xmlns': 'http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.13.0.xsd') {
            jdbc() {
                driver('org.postgresql.Driver')
                url('jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/metrics')
                user('postgres')
                password('pwd')
            }
            generator() {
                database() {
                    inputSchema('public')
                }

                // Watch out for this caveat when using MarkupBuilder with "reserved names"
                // - https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4797
                // - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389034/521799
                // - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/wi4S9rRxk4A
                generate() {
                }
                target() {
                    packageName('metrics.jooq')
                    directory('src/main/java')
                }
            }
        }
```

After I run gradle clean build it generates the code successfully but it cannot be compiled because it contains:

```
import org.jooq.TableOptions;
```

which cannot be resolved. How can I resolve this. It's very strange that it generates code that cannot be compiled...

I noticed that Gradle has downloaded version 3.11.9 instead of 3.13.3 for some reason.

After that I changed all the jooq related versions to 3.11.9 (also xsd version) in `build.gradle` and ran the build but got:

```
Error while reading XML configuration
```

Here is the end of the stack trace:

```
...
Caused by: org.jooq.codegen.GeneratorException: Error while reading XML configuration
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.load(GenerationTool.java:931)
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate(GenerationTool.java:218)
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool$generate.call(Unknown Source)
        at build_abyn1owj8gv09akc1mcgpsxr1.run(/media/wd/job/otr/mk/ufos-portal-incubate/solutions/mk-dashboard/build.gradle:56)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 104 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
        at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.load(GenerationTool.java:914)
        ... 108 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
        ... 109 more
```

I tried to resolve it as suggested here

https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9066

and added to `build.gradle`

```
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '3.0.0-M4'
        classpath group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '3.0.0-M4'
        classpath group: 'com.sun.activation', name: 'javax.activation', version: '1.2.0'
...
```

but without success

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem by using the right dependencies

Here is the excerpt from `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
   dependencies {
        classpath group: 'com.sun.activation', name: 'javax.activation', version: '1.2.0'
        classpath group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0.1'
        classpath group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.1'

        classpath 'org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.11.9'
        classpath 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
...
```